# Cassandra Node Stuck on Joining

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cassandra

Following is the trace

```
INFO  [Service Thread] 2017-04-03 16:03:12,892 GCInspector.java:284 - ConcurrentMarkSweep GC in 409ms.  CMS Old Gen: 735835280 -> 244369824; Code Cache: 19242240 -> 19422784; Metaspace: 33957296 -> 33963456; Par Eden Space: 5530560 -> 20738944; Par Survivor Space: 6324656 -> 10485760
INFO  [StreamReceiveTask:4] 2017-04-03 16:03:12,934 SecondaryIndexManager.java:365 - Submitting index build of rank_candidate_english_english,rank_candidate_english_rank for data in BigTableReader(path='/var/lib/cassandra/data/workindia/rank_candidate_english-cb5b37f0178d11e7bd24e7b9b065592d/mc-1-big-Data.db'),BigTableReader(path='/var/lib/cassandra/data/workindia/rank_candidate_english-cb5b37f0178d11e7bd24e7b9b065592d/mc-2-big-Data.db')
ERROR [StreamReceiveTask:2] 2017-04-03 16:04:23,887 StreamSession.java:534 - [Stream #a082a410-1886-11e7-bc70-ef55eb0b43e9] Streaming error occurred
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.waitOnFuture(FBUtilities.java:402) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
    at org.apache.cassandra.index.SecondaryIndexManager.buildIndexesBlocking(SecondaryIndexManager.java:373) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
    at org.apache.cassandra.index.SecondaryIndexManager.buildAllIndexesBlocking(SecondaryIndexManager.java:269) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamReceiveTask$OnCompletionRunnable.run(StreamReceiveTask.java:201) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.NamedThreadFactory.lambda$threadLocalDeallocator$0(NamedThreadFactory.java:79) [apache-cassandra-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.waitOnFuture(FBUtilities.java:398) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
    ... 9 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: null
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.AbstractIterator.next(AbstractIterator.java:64) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
    at org.apache.cassandra.index.SecondaryIndexManager.lambda$indexPartition$17(SecondaryIndexManager.java:598) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.cassandra.index.SecondaryIndexManager.indexPartition(SecondaryIndexManager.java:598) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
    at org.apache.cassandra.index.SecondaryIndexBuilder.build(SecondaryIndexBuilder.java:68) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager$11.run(CompactionManager.java:1337) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_121]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
INFO  [StreamReceiveTask:2] 2017-04-03 16:04:24,196 StreamResultFuture.java:183 - [Stream #a082a410-1886-11e7-bc70-ef55eb0b43e9] Session with /172.31.6.131 is complete
WARN  [StreamReceiveTask:2] 2017-04-03 16:04:24,197 StreamResultFuture.java:210 - [Stream #a082a410-1886-11e7-bc70-ef55eb0b43e9] Stream failed
ERROR [main] 2017-04-03 16:04:24,207 StorageService.java:1232 - Error while waiting on bootstrap to complete. Bootstrap will have to be restarted.
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamException: Stream failed
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:299) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:286) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.bootstrap(StorageService.java:1227) [apache-cassandra-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.joinTokenRing(StorageService.java:892) [apache-cassandra-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:659) [apache-cassandra-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:572) [apache-cassandra-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:346) [apache-cassandra-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:569) [apache-cassandra-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:697) [apache-cassandra-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
Caused by: org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamException: Stream failed
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamResultFuture.maybeComplete(StreamResultFuture.java:211) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamResultFuture.handleSessionComplete(StreamResultFuture.java:187) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.closeSession(StreamSession.java:440) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.onError(StreamSession.java:540) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamReceiveTask$OnCompletionRunnable.run(StreamReceiveTask.java:235) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.NamedThreadFactory.lambda$threadLocalDeallocator$0(NamedThreadFactory.java:79) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
WARN  [StreamReceiveTask:2] 2017-04-03 16:04:24,212 StorageService.java:1222 - Error during bootstrap.
org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamException: Stream failed
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.management.StreamEventJMXNotifier.onFailure(StreamEventJMXNotifier.java:85) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(Futures.java:1310) [guava-18.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:457) [guava-18.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:156) [guava-18.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:145) [guava-18.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:202) [guava-18.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamResultFuture.maybeComplete(StreamResultFuture.java:211) [apache-cassandra-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamResultFuture.handleSessionComplete(StreamResultFuture.java:187) [apache-cassandra-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.closeSession(StreamSession.java:440) [apache-cassandra-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.onError(StreamSession.java:540) [apache-cassandra-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamReceiveTask$OnCompletionRunnable.run(StreamReceiveTask.java:235) [apache-cassandra-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.NamedThreadFactory.lambda$threadLocalDeallocator$0(NamedThreadFactory.java:79) [apache-cassandra-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
WARN  [main] 2017-04-03 16:04:24,250 StorageService.java:944 - Some data streaming failed. Use nodetool to check bootstrap state and resume. For more, see `nodetool help bootstrap`. IN_PROGRESS
INFO  [main] 2017-04-03 16:04:24,251 CassandraDaemon.java:656 - Waiting for gossip to settle before accepting client requests...
INFO  [main] 2017-04-03 16:04:32,414 CassandraDaemon.java:687 - No gossip backlog; proceeding
INFO  [main] 2017-04-03 16:04:33,526 NativeTransportService.java:70 - Netty using native Epoll event loop
INFO  [main] 2017-04-03 16:04:34,374 Server.java:159 - Using Netty Version: [netty-buffer=netty-buffer-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-codec=netty-codec-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-codec-haproxy=netty-codec-haproxy-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-codec-http=netty-codec-http-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-codec-socks=netty-codec-socks-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-common=netty-common-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-handler=netty-handler-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-tcnative=netty-tcnative-1.1.33.Fork26.142ecbb, netty-transport=netty-transport-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-transport-native-epoll=netty-transport-native-epoll-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-transport-rxtx=netty-transport-rxtx-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-transport-sctp=netty-transport-sctp-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-transport-udt=netty-transport-udt-4.0.44.Final.452812a]
INFO  [main] 2017-04-03 16:04:34,376 Server.java:160 - Starting listening for CQL clients on /0.0.0.0:9042 (unencrypted)...
INFO  [main] 2017-04-03 16:04:35,150 CassandraDaemon.java:488 - Not starting RPC server as requested. Use JMX (StorageService->startRPCServer()) or nodetool (enablethrift) to start it
```

Follow stuff have been tried:
1. delete data, commitlogs, saved_cache folder and restart
2. nodetool scrub --skip-corrupted and then again tried bootstrapping
3. Have tried multiple stuff

Note: I had a dead node which I removed but I still see that in gossip. 
Can that be an issue?
How to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting this error because of index.

Are you using any custom index ? If yes then make sure the custom index jar is in the new cassandra node. If this not solved your problem then try to drop all the index then join the new node, After joining completed you can recreate all the index

You can check out this link on joining new node :
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsAddNodeToCluster.html

Comment: If possible could you guide me with a tutorial?
I am bit newbie

Comment: You can check out this link on joining new node :
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsAddNodeToCluster.html